# "The record has been deleted since you retrieved it" when creating an item receipt from PO

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am importing CSV file with the following JSON :

```
[{"po":"POUSOPS50000","item":"Test Item 1","quantity":"400"},{"po":"POUSOPS50000","item":"Test Item 2","quantity":"700"}]
```

I want to create one item receipt that includes both two items in the CSV.

When I importing the file its create one item receipt with only the first item (first object in JSON)
and it trow me an ERROR "The record has been deleted since you retrieved it."

my code:

```
function Run(irList) {
    try {
        

        var poName = irList[Object.keys(irList)[0]]["po"]; 

        var poId = getPO(poName)

        var irRec = context.record.transform({
            fromType: 'purchaseorder',
            fromId: poId,
            toType: 'itemreceipt'
        })

        var count = irRec.getLineCount('item')

        for (; i < irList.length; i++) {
            var irData = irList[i];


            createIR(irData, irRec, count, poId)

            var irId = irRec.save({
                ignoreMandatoryFields: true
            });

    } catch (e) {
        log.error('Run ' + i, e)
        errorsList.push({
            action: 'Run ' + i,
            m: e.message
        })
    }
```

```
function createIR(irData, irRec, count, poId) {

//irData = one item object
//irRec = item receipt object (after transform from po)
//count = the number of items in po
//poId = PO id

    try {

        var sublistId = 'item'

        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            irRec.setSublistValue(sublistId, 'quantity', i, '')
        }

        var itemId = getItemId(irData.item)

        var quantity = irData.quantity


        for (var i = 0; i < count && quantity; i++) {

            var item = irRec.getSublistValue(sublistId, 'item', i)

            if (item == itemId) {

                var qtyRem = irRec.getSublistValue(sublistId,
                    'quantityremaining', i)

                var diff = qtyRem - quantity

                if (diff >= 0) {
                    irRec.setSublistValue(sublistId, 'quantity', i, quantity)
                    break;
                } else {
                    quantity -= qtyRem
                    irRec.setSublistValue(sublistId, 'quantity', i, qtyRem)
                }
            }
        }

        var irId = irRec.save({
            ignoreMandatoryFields: true
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two functions named run and all three of the functions are saving the item receipt record you transformed.  That is a weird error since I don't see you deleting anything.  can you post your script in its entirety?

Comment: Its was missing with copy the code. there is only one Run function there now.